# Multiple checked selectors CSS not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm making my own toggle thing in CSS but I have a problem. Only the top selector works. The bottom one doesn't. Is there a way to solve/get around this? Also, the same thing happens when I switch the ordering of the selectors so it isn't a classname issue.

```
        .toggle__checkbox:checked + .toggle__wrap{
            background-color: #D24D57;
            border-color: #D24D57;
            transition: background-color .25s, border-color .25s;
        }
        .toggle__checkbox:checked + .toggle__button{
            margin-left: 20px;
            transition: margin-left .25s;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michael_B Do you want me to put less code?

Comment: An ability to reproduce the problem you're having would be useful.

Comment: Please include your HTML as well. Better still make a snippet demonstrating the problem. Use the `<>` button in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm guessing without the HTML for context but the problem is likely due to the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). This will select only the immediate element following `.toggle__checkbox:checked`.

With some HTML in your question I would be able to know for sure and make a suggestion.